# Convert string (arithmetic operation)

Tags: javascript

I need convert `"100% - 1"` to `300 - 1` where 300 - canvas width? How to eval (batch) this operation?

```
//for example:
var value = batch("100% - 1", canvas.width); //Must 299, because canvas.width is 300
var secondary = batch("50% + 10", canvas.width); //Must 160
//where first argument - arithmetic operation, second - relativity value.
```

This question is not from the scope of science fiction, but a very serious and real issue.

**Update!** But if need just convert percentage?

```
var value = hack("75%", 300); //Must 255
var operation = hack("30%", 100) + 10; //Must 40
var end = hack("1em", somearg); //EM?
```

**Update2!** What a will, if i use `new Function("a", "b", "return (%%Expression%%)")` instead of `eval`?

For example:

```
var operation = "90% - 10";
```

To:

```
new Function("a", "return ((a * 90 / 100) - 10)");
```

How to made it?

Comment: Why don't you just use `var anything = (canvas.width * (percent / 100)) + somenumber;` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have two parts in the *batch* and the first is always a percentage and second a value then you could do

```
function batch(operation, value){
    var values = operation.match(/\d+|[+-/*]/g),
        percent = parseFloat(values[0])/100,
        relative = parseFloat(values[2]),
        math = values[1],
        applied = percent*value;

     switch(math){
         case '+': return applied + relative; 
         case '-': return applied - relative;
         case '/': return applied / relative;
         case '*': return applied * relative;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a replace and simple mat rule,

what 100% of width actually is (100 / 100 * width) so you can do following.

```
function batch(calcStr, objWidth)
{
calcStr = calcStr.replace("%", "/100*" + objWidth);
var newWidth = eval(calcStr); 
// The + 10 or -1 are already there...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
expr = expr.replace(/(\d+)%/g, function($0, $1) { return width * parseInt($1) / 100 })
result = eval(expr)
```

If your expressions are always if form `xxx% + yyy` you can also get along without `eval`:

```
expr = expr.replace(/(\d+)%/g, function($0, $1) { return width * parseInt($1) / 100 })
result = expr.replace(/(\d+)\s*([+-*/])\s*(\d+)/g, function($0, $1, $2, $3) { 
    $1 = parseInt($1);
    $3 = parseInt($3);
    switch($2) {
        case '+': return $1 + $2;
        etc.....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to compute that, you can use a regular expression to search for all occurences of a number followed by a percent sign:

```
expression = "30% + 10";
m = /(\d+)%/.exec( expression );
```

this will give you the whole match (30%) as m[0] and
just the numbers (30) as m[1](http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/XMhRQ/19/).

You can use this to calculate the new value

```
v = width_100_percent * parseInt(m[1]) / 100;
```

and then replace it for real, and eval the resulting
mathemtatical expression.

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjelline/XMhRQ/19/) for a working example.

**But!**

Evaling and expression that might have been user input
at some point opens up the whole subject of security ... so you
shouls think really, really, really hard about how to avoid
this situation.

**My Guess**

You are going to all this trouble because you want to do
some calculation for CSS layouts.  So here are my to suggestions
of how you might avoid the calculation:

**1)  box-sizing: border-box**

the classical box model makes it practically impossible to do stuff like
"split this div into three equal columns with borders of 1px each".

look into the new "border-box" which make this really simple: with border-box
the padding + border count as part of the width, so

```
  width: 30%
  border: 1px;
```

actually adds up to 100%.

See [Paul Irish's article](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) for a more detailed explanation.

**2) CSS preprocessors like SASS or LESS**

if you want to do computations in your CSS you can use
a preprocessor to do that for you.   Both [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)
support variables and mathematical expression, with a slight
difference in syntax:

```
  padding: $x / 2;

  padding: (@x / 2);
```

So there you are: one way to implement what you wanted, and two ways to avoid it.